# How do I get the indices of current selected rows in bootstrap vue's table when doing range selection?

Tags: vue.js

in this example: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#row-select-support

if I do range selection like this:

[image]

the array index list will surely be: `[0, 1, 2]`

How do I make it: `[0, 1, 3]` . Hence, the conclusion is it gets the indices of current selected rows

tried this:

```
<b-table
                ref="refTable"
                :fields="tableHeaderColumn"
                :busy="tableBusy"
                :items="tableItems"
                class="position-relative"
                empty-text="No matching records found"
                primary-key="id"
                responsive="sm"
                show-empty
                selectable
                sticky-header="500px"
                select-mode="range"
                @row-clicked="clickedRowsEvt"
            >
     ....
</b-table>

const selectedRowsIndices = ref([]);

const clickedRowsEvt = (item, index) => {
      selectedRowsIndices.value.push(index);    
};
```

It keeps pushing the row index which I don't want. But I don't know what to do next

Comment: it's interesting that you got this far, as `bootsrap-vue` doesn't support Vue 3, according to [this Github issue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196)

Comment: I'm not using Vue 3. That's actually composition api. this problem's solved by using v-model

Comment: Ok, I didn’t think of the Composition API in Vue 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself. you can take it a look at: https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/LYboxBV

The v-model on `<b-table>` will return an array of the currently rendered page after sorting and pagination

```html
<div id="app">
  <b-table v-model="currentItems" bordered sort-by="age" :items="items" selectable select-mode="range" @row-selected="onSelect"></b-table>
</div>
```